Which ed25519 PEM keys does openssh >9.6 support?
According to the release notes of OpenSSH 9.6 it now supports ED25519 keys in PEM format

ssh(1), sshd(8), ssh-add(1), ssh-keygen(1): add support for    reading
ED25519 private keys in PEM PKCS8 format. Previously    only the
OpenSSH private key format was supported.

I some how seem to be unable to generate a ED25519 private either with ssh-keygen or openssl that is both really a PEM key and is accepted by the above mentioned OpenSSH commands.
The commands in the documentation do not work for me (still resulting in only OpenSSH format keys like in OpenSSH <9.6 ). Particularly also generating an ED25519 PEM key using openssl does not work.

If I run ssh-keygen -m PEM I get private key in OpenSSH format (-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----) ,  If I run openssl genpkey -outform PEM the ED25519 key is not usable via ssh.

I think I found the problem: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/8d0e46c1ddb5b7f0992591b0dc5d8aaa77cc9dba

If Harry's answer helped then you should tick it.  Otherwise please post your answer below.

...add support for reading ED25519 private keys in PEM PKCS8 format. Copied from your own question, notice the word READ, maybe it can't create them?

@till I've tested OpenSSH 9.8p1 (Debian 13) that should include this patch, and it doesn't fix the issue.

From the article
Create SSH Key Using PEM, RSA and ED25519 :

Generate a PEM key pair on Linux
This can be generated based on two algorithms previously covered above
which are rsa and ed25519.
To generate a pem format key pair based on rsa algorithm, open your
terminal and run the following command:
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -C your_email@example.com

To generate pem key pair based on ed25519 algorithm, use the following
command
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -m PEM -C your_email@example.com

Remember you can change the key size -b 4096 to any size of your
choice which should be factors of 1024 like 2048, 4096 and 8192 which
matches the computer memory space allocation (*in simpler terms)
Factors to note

On the prompt for key name, enter an absolute path with a new file name that does not exist in the destination path to create a new key,
or with a name that exists to overwrite the existing key in the
entered path location.
Using the default path, will overwrite any keys created prior to the current generation using the default key name.
On the paraphrase prompt you may enter any paraphrase of your choice but you must save it securely since you wont be able to use the
private key without its paraphrase.
You can actually enter no paraphrase and create an open key pair which means anyone with access to this private key may use it freely.



This is what the documentation says but the resulting private key for  me is "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----". Have you checked the result?

If -m PEM doesn't work for you, this is a bug that you need to signal.

Does it work for you then? The article you linked is from 2022  and it is highly unlikely that it worked for anyone at this point (because it is supposed to work only from 9.6). As commented above. 9.6 and 9.7 builds seem to have a problem, which is why the feature never landed.
